# Understanding XCTestCase life cycle - How to perform setup BEFORE Xcode unit test launches the app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing

I am new to unit tests in Xcode and Swift and have some trouble to understand the life cycle of `XCTestCase`.

**How/where to add setup code which is executed before the actual app is launched?**

Problem is, that first the host app is launched before any of the test setup methods (`class func setUp()`, `func setUp()`, `func setUpWithError()`) are executed.

It is even possible to run test code before the host app launches?

---

**Details:**

As described in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69452935/777861) my app uses a SQLite database to persist some data. When the app launches a database connection is created and data is read from the database.

To make tests consistent and repeatable I would like to use a fresh database with some well defined data every time a run the test. To archive this I tried to override `setUpWithError` remove the existing db file and move a file with pre-defined data in place instead.

Unfortunately this does not work, because `setUpWithError` is executed only **after** the host app was launched. The same is true for all other test setup methods.

Moving a fresh database file in place before running the tests is only an example. The problem is the same for all local data which should be in place **before** the host app launches to ensure repeatable tests.

An answer to my previous question included a `UIApplication` extension with a `isTesting` method which can be used to check if a test is performed. While I could use this in my app code to setup the test data, I would consider this a bad solution. I would like to keep the code completely separated from the production code. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches to set up data before running a test case

### NSPrincipalClass

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822457/how-to-run-one-time-setup-code-before-executing-any-xctest) you can create a class, and the `init` method of that class is executed before running any test. This helps setting up dependencies used by many test cases. I don't think this is the way to go in your case.

### `isTesting`

Instead of setting up the code in your app target, you can also check for `isTesting` early in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of your `AppDelegate` and simply `return` there. In this case the regular code is not executed and you can run you custom database setup code in the `setup` of your test class.

### Dependency Injection

Right now you are doing **integration testing** in my opinion. If you want to have proper **unit tests**, they should not operate against the database of the underlying app. Instead create an extra (in memory) database and inject that into the code you are testing. I think this is the way you should follow. The benefits are

- Your app is not affected by your tests. Next time you start the app to manually test, your original data is still there.
- Your unit tests are not affected by manual changes to the app
- Your unit tests are also independent of each other. Order of execution doesn't change the results when setting up the database fresh for each test case.

Comment: Looks like isTesting is deprecated: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestprobe/1501028-istesting?changes=_3&language=objc

Answer (score 0):

> It is even possible to run test code before the host app launches

If you have to ask that, your tests are not unit tests. Unit tests test *code*, not the *app*. A test that requires the app to be running would be a UI test.

In fact, the best approach for unit tests is to put all your testable code into a framework and give the framework unit tests; that way, your tests run much faster because the app never has to launch at all.

It sounds to me like the problem lies deeper in your app's code: you have evidently not written your code in such a way as to *be* testable. So that would be your first move. Writing testable code, and writing unit tests, is an art; you have to separate out the "system under test", which should be *your* code alone, and make sure you are *not* testing anything that doesn't belong to you and whose workings are already known — like Core Data.